# Bijective and Bijection of A onto B

Tags: functions

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$, $A=(x\in \mathbb{R}| x\ne3)$ and
 $$f=\frac{2x}{x-3}$$

I'm arguing this with my teacher that this function is not bijective (my opinion). I know it is injective. But when we choose counterexample $f(x)=2$, it concluded $∄\,x\in A,\,\text{such that} \,\frac{2x}{x-3}=2$

So that's mean $f(x)$ isn't onto. Hence in my opinion this function isn't bijective. I assume this function is $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.

Besides, as far as i know. A function is onto if all codomain is range ($f(x)=R_f$). For example $f(x)=x$.

But, my teacher said that it's onto. And Bijective. Cz it has range 
$$R_f=(x|x\in \mathbb R,\, x \ne 2)$$

From this range, my teacher concluded that this function is bijective or a bijection of A and B.
A(i've described)
B(all real number except 2. It's my teacher's opinion) (But i don't think we're referring to this range ($f(x)$). We have to referring to the co-domain that is all real numbers)
Then i try to think a contradiction.
If my teacher concluded like that. So, all function is onto(surjective) right? Cz they have a surjection to their range. My teacher said Yes. But what about the codomain. I'm really confused.

I tried to checked on wolfram alpha. It said that this function is neither onto nor bijective.

There is no infornation about the codomain is. But i assumed this function is $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.

Comment: If $B$ has to be $R_f$ for it to be bijective.  What is $B$?

Comment: There is no information... i got this on my teacher's PPT. But i assumed that B is all Real numbers.

Comment: Your argument with your teacher is an argument over notation.  Obviously any $1-1$ function is bijective onto its range.  In other words, it doesn't make sense to talk about a function being bijective unless you *first* specify both its domain and the "target."

Comment: I've found that B is a real number. The domain is A (i've described it on my question). I think it's specific enough right? I have domain and codomain here.